# create bucket table in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I tried below query to create a bucket table but failed. However, if I remove
the clause `CLUSTERED BY`, the query could succeed. Any suggestion? Thank you.

the error message: `no viable alternative at input create external`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE nation5(
  n_nationkey bigint, 
  n_name string, 
  n_rgionkey int, 
  n_comment string)
CLUSTERED BY 
  n_regionkey INTO 256 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'path'='s3://test/testbucket/nation5/') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://test/testbucket/nation5/'
```

Comment: did get the performance improvement with a bucketed table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CLUSTERED BY` column needs to be in brackets, the following works:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test.nation5(
  n_nationkey bigint, 
  n_name string, 
  n_regionkey int, 
  n_comment string)
CLUSTERED BY 
  (n_regionkey) INTO 256 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'path'='s3://test/testbucket/nation5/') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://test/testbucket/nation5/'
```

(You also have a spelling mistake in `n_rgionkey` in the column definition.